# Numba. How to write np.sum with a tuple axis parameter?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

THis code :

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def foo(x):
    return x.sum(axis=(1,2))

x=np.linspace(0,1)
x=x.reshape(5,5,-1)
print(foo(x))
```

returns this error :

```
NotImplementedError: No definition for lowering array.sum(array(float64, 3d, C), Tuple(Literal[int](1), Literal[int](2))) -> array(float64, 2d, C)
```

It seems that **numba** supports *np.sum* when *axis* parameter is only an integer, not a tuple of integer (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html#numpy.ndarray.sum).
So, I use this workaround `return x.sum(axis=1).sum(axis=1)` but it is not a good solution if I consider code optimization.

Does it exist another solution or must I wait for a future numba version ?

Answer (score 2):

Just reshape your array to one dimension more than your desired result.  In your example:

```
x.sum(axis=(1,2))
```

can be replaced by:

```
x.reshape(5,-1).sum(axis=1)
```

which produces the same result and can be executed by Numba.